# imbalance ratio in R?

Tags: r

I have got many imbalanced data sets and I am balancing them with algorithms such as SMOTE etc. **all data are regression data.** for comparison of data before and after, I need to calculate imbalance ratio of these regression data.

I have searched a lot but in vain. I am working in R language.

how can we calculate imbalance ratio of regression data set in R language?
IR(imbalance ratio) of binary data= no of majority class instances/ no of minority class instances

Comment: you need to give some kind of pointer (e.g. a description or URL) to how the imbalance ratio is calculated.  Most readers here, including myself, will have no idea what you're talking about.  Have you tried `library("sos"); findFn("imbalance")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your problem is a binary classification one and the data set `df` has a column named `Class`, you can use a function like this to calculate the imbalance ratio:

```
getIMR <- function(df){
    minCl <- names(which.min(table(df$Class)))
    sum(df$Class!=minCl)/sum(df$Class==minCl)
}
```

Do note that I have assumed the definition of imbalance ratio as `N_majority/N_minority`

Comment: thanks! I have binary data, as well as data with upto 5 classes and also regression data. what is your opinion about imbalance ratio of regression data?

Comment: @AsaadGhufran : It would depend on how you want to define them. I'm not aware of any standard representation for multi-class and regression data